# How to prevent overflow-wrap: break-word; from creating a new line for words that are too long?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the value of key "abc" on the same line as the property without making the text not wrap?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        div{
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>{
    "abc": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t think that will be possible, not with all of the text contained in a single element. If you had one container element _per line_ of text (talking the original line breaks here, not the word wrapping), then you could probably work with text-indent and some margin or padding. (And you’d still have to know by how much `"abc"` was indented in the first place.)

Comment: Why use `break-word` if you don't want words to break?

Comment: I only want it to break when there are too many characters for one line.

Comment: Example of what I was talking about in the comment above: https://jsfiddle.net/pes85jfv/ You also have to figure out the appropriate “magic number”for the indentation, that matches the amount of space those leading spaces before the key generate.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
```

```html
<div>
{    "abc":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}
</div>
```

Comment: I need the text to wrap

Comment: so all you have to do is remove the space between ```:``` and ```"```

Comment: Yes but that makes it less readable.